# Sorting array data by common date

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a .csv file with many rows and 3 columns:  Date, Rep, and Sales.  I would like to use Python to generate a new array that groups the data by Date and, for the given date, sorts the Reps by Sales.  As an example, my input data looks like this:

```
salesData = [[201703,'Bob',3000], [201703,'Sarah',6000], [201703,'Jim',9000], 
    [201704,'Bob',8000], [201704,'Sarah',7000], [201704,'Jim',12000], 
    [201705,'Bob',15000], [201705,'Sarah',14000], [201705,'Jim',8000],
    [201706,'Bob',10000], [201706,'Sarah',18000]]
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
sortedData = [[201703,'Jim', 'Sarah', 'Bob'], [201704,'Jim', 'Bob', 
    'Sarah'], [201705,'Bob', 'Sarah', 'Jim'], [201706, 'Sarah', 'Bob']]
```

I am new to Python, but I have searched quite a bit for a solution with no success.  Most of my search results lead me to believe there may be an easy way to do this using pandas (which I have not used) or numpy (which I have used).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pandas!

```
import pandas as pd

salesData = [[201703, 'Bob', 3000], [201703, 'Sarah', 6000], [201703, 'Jim', 9000],
             [201704, 'Bob', 8000], [201704, 'Sarah', 7000], [201704, 'Jim', 12000],
             [201705, 'Bob', 15000], [201705, 'Sarah', 14000], [201705, 'Jim', 8000],
             [201706, 'Bob', 10000], [201706, 'Sarah', 18000]]

sales_df = pd.DataFrame(salesData)
result = []
for name, group in sales_df.groupby(0):
    sorted_df = group.sort_values(2, ascending=False)
    result.append([name] + list(sorted_df[1]))
print(result)
```

Comment: Wow - that's awesome!  I am definitely going to need to read up on pandas - so easy and powerful.  Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without pandas, you can try this one line answer:

```
sortedData = [[i]+[item[1] for item in salesData if item[0]==i] for i in sorted(set([item[0] for item in salesData]))]
```

---

**EDIT:**

 You can do this to order each inner list by sales:

```
sortedData = [[i]+[item[1] for item in sorted(salesData, key=lambda x: -x[2]) if item[0]==i] for i in sorted(set([item[0] for item in salesData]))]
```

Note that `sorted(salesData, key=lambda x: -x[2])` part performs the ordering

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am going to go with the pandas solution, but I'd still like to understand your code better as I'm new to learning Python.  One problem I had running this line of code was that the output is in the correct format (i.e. unique dates followed by a list of names), but the names are not sorted by sales.  Is there a way to add this functionality to your code?  Thanks!