# Nested for-loop to create list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the below code, and as someone new to Python, I was hoping for suggestions on making it more Pythonic.  Posters in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505133/sorting-array-data-by-common-date/44505794#44505794) have provided very helpful numpy and list comprehension solutions; however, I'd like to improve my more basic nested loop solution solely for the sake of becoming better with basic Python tasks (please do let me know if I should have posted this in the prior thread instead of starting a new semi-duplicate...apologies if that's what I should have done).

Here's the current code (which works as desired):

```
sales_data = [[201703, 'Bob', 3000], [201703, 'Sarah', 6000], [201703, 
'Jim', 9000], [201704, 'Bob', 8000], [201704, 'Sarah', 7000], [201704, 
'Jim', 12000], [201705, 'Bob', 15000], [201705, 'Sarah', 14000], [201705, 
'Jim', 8000], [201706, 'Bob', 10000], [201706, 'Sarah', 18000]]

sorted_sales_data = sorted(sales_data, key=lambda x: -x[2])
date_list = []
sales_ranks = []

for i in sales_data:
    date_list.append(i[0])

sorted_dates = sorted(set(date_list), reverse=True)

for i in sorted_dates:
    tmp_lst = []
    tmp_lst.append(i)
    for j in sorted_sales_data:
        if j[0] == i:
            tmp_lst.append(j[1])
    sales_ranks.append(tmp_lst)

print(sales_ranks)
```

Any suggestions on making this more Pythonic (other than numpy or list comprehension solutions) would be greatly appreciated.  I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ provides a code review community where you can post things like this as well

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have added my post [there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166794/nested-for-loop-to-create-list-of-lists-python).